# Animate contentOffset when contentSize become smaller the frame size in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have UICollectionView with 2 sections. Each section is 75% height of screen frame height. 
The screen is scrolled to the bottom, so I see 25% of the first section and 100% of second one.

Then I reload the second section and its height becomes only 10% of the frame height (so I can see them both on the screen) - the screen jumps to the top.

As contentSize becomes smaller than the frame, it set contentOffset to 0, so the screen jumps to the top.

I want to "animate" the jump, so the screen scrolled to the top. Probably, I need to setContentOffset:Animated when the contentSize becomes smaller then the screen frame.

Any idea where I can do it to properly animate it?

PS. I've tried sticking observer to contentSize and setContentOffset:Animated over there, but it doesn't do anything.